# The balled (headed) eagle?

Tags: etymology, american-english, animals, clipping

> Now I observe you staring upward and puzzling your wits to guess what great bird it is you see wheeling aloft over our heads. That, Sir, is the type, symbol, and adopted emblem of our nation, the BALD EAGLE, **who, by the way, is not bald,** any more than that stout and sturdy youth, the thriving republic, whose character he represents; only his head and neck are white; so is his tail; the rest of his body is brown. — *[New England Magazine](https://books.google.it/books?id=X8FSAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA231&dq=%22adopted%20emblem%20of%20our%20nation,%20the%20BALD%20EAGLE%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22adopted%20emblem%20of%20our%20nation%2C%20the%20BALD%20EAGLE%22&f=false)*, Vol 1, 1831
>
> [emphasis in bold mine]

[image: (photograph)]

The Latin name for this iconic raptor is *Haliaeetus leucocephalus*, which means **white-headed sea eagle**. The  *Hali* is Greek for “sea” and *Aiētēs* is “eagle”. Meanwhile, its species name is derived from *leucos*, “white” and *cephalus* which means “head”.

In 1782 the bald eagle was designated by Congress to represent the, then fledgling, United States. It is a fine and majestic-looking predatory bird but its head is amply covered with snow-white feathers: to put it bluntly, it is not bald. On the other hand, the **immature bald eagle has a mixture of brown and white feathers** until its fourth or fifth year of life when the distinctive solid-white head and white tail fully appear.

Etymonline says *[bald](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bald)*, meaning the lack of hair, is from the 14th century but its origin is uncertain, it suggests that it could have been derived from Celtic ***bal*** meaning “white patch, blaze”.
*A Middle English Dictionary* (Oxford, 1891) suggests that *bald* comes from the Old English for **ball**:  *beal*, *beall*, dating  back to c. 1200.

Etymonline also notes the following:

> Bald eagle first attested 1680s; so called for its white head.

I also read that the raptor's name was taken from **piebald** ([source](https://www.nps.gov/kefj/learn/nature/bald-eagle.htm)), a word that first appeared in 1590 according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piebald) and means patches of black and white. Oxford Dictionaries states that  *pie* recalls the magpie's black-and-white plumage, and bald (*[in the obsolete sense ‘streaked with white’](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/piebald)*).

So now I am quite confused. What do I tell my 12-year-old Italian student on Monday when he comes back for his lesson and point-blank refuses to believe that the bald eagle is *bald*? Can't say I blame him.

### Question

1. **Why was the white-headed eagle named “bald”**?
   Is it because

   - its white head resembles a smooth spherical ball?
   - *bald* used to mean “streaked with white”?
   - *bald* used to mean “a white patch, blaze”?
   - because in flight it looks *bald*?
   - OR because its feathers are dark brown and white, and *bald* was/is a back-formation or clipping  of the 16th-century term *piebald.*

Comment: Wigs and outré hair styles were all the rage among the other eagles back in the day, so the uninspired, dowdy sleekness of this one made them call him bald. In true fighting spirit, the bald eagle owned this slur and took it for himself. Eventually, their minimalist style became a trend, and gone are the days now when you’d see the other eagles all coiffed up in their whilom dos.

Comment: I can't resist mentioning the time that my younger sibling misheard the lyrics  of ["More Than a Woman"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_Than_a_Woman_(Bee_Gees_song)) as "bald headed woman"!

Comment: Bald doesn't just mean not having hair.  (In that sense, of course, all birds are bald :-))  When used with landscapes, it can mean bare or barren, as in "Night on Bald Mountain".

Comment: Okay, interesting question. What does the title have to do with anything? No ballas here.

Comment: @cat *bald*  used to be written "balled".

Comment: Not totally related and probably goes without saying, but of course the Italian student can't start too early in coming to grips with the complete illogic that is ubiquitous in the English language, and not at all just in terms of etymology.

Comment: When I was a kid, my father told me a (probably apocryphal) anecdote about an early-20th century author of scandalous novels, who met a young fan at a reception.  She loved his novels, but was too innocent to understand all the references; hence the following exchange:  She: "Sir, I am dying to ask - what is a eunuch?"  He: "A eunuch is a bald (balled) man."  She: "Then are you a eunuch?"  He: "No, I'm too bald (two-balled)."

Comment: @MT_Head That joke doesn't work here, because we all would have asked her what research she had done.

Comment: And what is the etymology of "bald"??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The earliest attested spelling of the word *bald* seems to be *balled,* as you have noticed. According to the Oxford English Dictionary (OED), "Middle English *balled*" is "**of uncertain origin**".

However, the use of "bald" to describe animals that have white streaks/spots/markings is attested well before the specific term "bald eagle". So it seems quite plausible that the bald eagle was simply named this because it was *bald,* as in, marked with white on its head. However, it is probably also not a coincidence that this white head resembles a hairless (*bald*) human head.

The OED gives it as the fifth definition:

> 5. Streaked or marked with white.

with the following examples:

> - 1568   in W. Greenwell Wills & Inventories Registry Durham (1860) II. ii. 297   A little **belled** meare and a fole.
> - [1594   R. Barnfield Affectionate Shepheard i. xxviii. sig. Bijv   I haue a **pie-bald** Curre to hunt the Hare.]
> - 1690   London Gaz. No. 2575/4   A black Mare with 3 white Feet, and a **bald** Face.
> - 1711   London Gaz. No. 4848/4   Strayed..a black **bald** Gelding.

The [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=bald&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) (AHD) gives it as the fourth sense:

> *Zoology* Having white feathers or markings on the head, as in some birds or mammals

So I would say, **just tell your student that it is a specialized/obsolete use of "bald" that most speakers are not familar with.**

This sense of *bald* also seems to be the origin of the word *piebald* (which occurs in one of the OED examples above). The AHD entry for *[piebald](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=piebald&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)* says:

> [PIE](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=PIE)<sup>2</sup> [as in "magpie") + Early Modern English *bald,* marked or streaked with white.

Thus, *bald eagle* and the word *piebald* seem to be indirectly related. However, neither the OED nor the AHD seems to be in favor of describing "bald eagle" as having been *directly* derived from "piebald" (an etymology that Michael Seifert mentioned in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405245/the-balled-headed-eagle/405314#comment964334_405251)); i.e., I can't find any evidence that people used to call this animal a name like "piebald eagle" and then that was later shortened to "bald eagle".

### Two etymologies that have been suggested for this sense of *bald*

The origin of *bald* in this sense seems especially unclear. It might be derived from the noun *ball,* which apparently doesn't have an attested cognate/ancestor in Old English but which seems to have cognates in some other Germanic languages. The OED says "ball" is

> Probably the reflex of an unattested Old English **beall* (compare Old English *bealluc* bollock n.), cognate with Middle Dutch *bal* ball, sphere (Dutch *bal* ball, sphere, ball of the foot, heel of the hand), Middle Low German *bal* ball, ball of the foot, heel of the hand, Old High German *bal* ball for playing, small sphere, mouthful (Middle High German *bal* ball, globe, ball of the foot, German *Ball*), Old Icelandic *bǫllr* ball, sphere, hill, Norwegian *ball* ball, Old Swedish *balder, baller* ball (Swedish *boll,* (regional) *ball, balle*), Old Danish *bold* ball (Danish bold ball), and further with Old High German *ballo, pallo* (weak masculine) ball of the foot, heel of the hand, mouthful, ball for playing (Middle High German *balle* ball, sphere, ball of the foot, heel of the hand), and Old High German *balla, palla* (weak feminine) ball for playing, mouthful < the same Indo-European base as classical Latin *follis* inflated ball, bellows, and (with different ablaut grade) ancient Greek *ϕαλλός* penis, image of the (usually erect) penis, especially as a symbol of the generative power in nature (see *phallos* n.). Compare *bale* n.3 for forms in Romance languages probably borrowed ultimately < the same Germanic base.

However, as you note, several sources suggest *bald* in the particular meaning "having white spots/streaks/a white spot/a white streak" is instead related to, or in some way also associated with Welsh "bal":

OED:

> Compare Welsh *ceffyl bàl* a horse with a white streak or mark on the face (French *cheval belle-face*), where *bàl* may be an adjective, or a noun construed as a genitive.

AHD:

> Sense 4 ["*Zoology* Having white feathers or markings on the head, as in some birds or mammals"] perhaps partly of Celtic origin; akin to Welsh *bal,* having a white streak on the forehead (of horses), Irish *ball,* spot, mark, and English *blaze,* white mark on the face of an animal; see BLAZE<sup>2</sup>.

The word *[blaze](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=blaze&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)* is traced back by the [AHD to the PIE root](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/indoeurop.html)

> ‌‌ bhel-<sup>1</sup>
>   To shine, flash, burn; shining white and various bright colors.

Which is identical in form with, but treated as a distinct root from

> ‌‌ bhel-<sup>2</sup>
>   To blow, swell; with derivatives referring to various round objects and to the notion of tumescent masculinity.

Comment: +1 for explaining the spelling of "balled" in the title. Thank you! And the rest of the answer is pretty good too. :P

Comment: But do you know why the bald eagle was given this title? Why not "white-headed eagle" if it's because of its white head? Why not "American eagle"? There are no exemplars of this species beyond the American continent.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Unfortunately, I don't know yet why it was given this name rather than another one. The OED does define it as "The [American eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Eagle)" so it seems this is another name for it that has been used, but that didn't end up being as popular.

Comment: Aha "yet"... Does that mean you are digging to find out why? Excellent. Happy hunting.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yes, I think I will try to do a bit more research and update this answer if I find anything else :) Thanks.

Comment: By the way, is the breakdown of Haliaeetos into *Hali* and *Aiētēs* correct? I got conflicting information from the net, especially about the meanings and spelling of the former. *Haliaetos*, *Hali* = "salt", *Halos* etc...  I settled for Hali in the end, but I don't want to contribute to the misinformation if I can help it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: *haliaeetus* seems to be a Latinization of Greek *Ἁλιά(ι)ετος.*   The second part of this word is apparently from [*ἀ(ι)ετός*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ἀετός#Ancient_Greek) (*a(i)etos*), Ancient Greek for "eagle". Wikipedia has an article on a king called [Aeëtes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeëtes) that seems to imply that the name *Αἰήτης* (*Aiētēs*) is a variant form or synonym of *ἀετός.*

Comment: (The spelling with "aee" is based on a pronunciation with a diphthong *αι* that was lost in some dialects of Greek, but retained in others: see Cerberus's answer to a [question I asked on Latin SE about "poeta"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/439) for a description of a similar situation.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: The first part is from some form of the word [*ἅλς*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ἅλς#Ancient_Greek) (*hals*), which it seems could refer to either "salt" or "the sea", but I don't know enough about Greek to say why it takes the particular form *ἁλι-* (*hali-*) in this compound word.

Comment: A note on the Wikipedia page ["Sea eagle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_eagle) explains *ἁλι-* as coming from the dative case form of *ἅλς*, but I don't see any citation for that statement. If you want to know more, you might ask about the construction of this word on Latin SE, or if you are patient, sign up for Greek SE and ask when it is up and running!

Comment: So I'm right, it is confusing. No  Latin or Greek SE for me, thank you. You are free to post the question in SE Biology (not sure about it being on-topic) if it has piqued your interest though!

Answer (score 18):

OED unequivocally derives the first morpheme in “bald eagle” (or “bald-eagle”) from the ordinary sense of *bald* as “Having no hair on some part of the head where it would naturally grow; hairless.”

In the entry for the bird, the following two extracts lead the shortish list:

> 1692   R. Frame *Descr. Pennsylv.* 27   The Turky-Buzard and Bald-Eagle high, Wild Ducks, which in great Companyes do fly.
>
> 1694   *Philos. Trans. 1693* (Royal Soc.) 17 989   The Second is the Bald Eagle, for the Body and part of the Neck being of a dark brown, the upper part of the Neck and Head is covered with a white sort of Down, whereby it looks very bald, whence it is so named.

Count this slander upon *[Migizi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/migizi)* among the many misnomers that we *[gichi-mookomaanag](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gichi-mookomaan)* visited upon the creatures of Turtle Island, starting of course with *Indians* for *[Anishinaabeg](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Anishinaabe)* and also including *wild rice* for *manoomin.*

And yes, “R. Frame” should definitely keep his day job—versification clearly is not his forte.

Comment: It's worth noting that there are a large number of sources online (including Wikipedia) that say that "bald" is a shortening of "piebald" in this context.  However, that theory may well be one of those folk etymologies that has taken on a life of its own.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: the word *piebald* itself seems to be derived from *bald,* so either etymology seems like it would lead back to the same place. However, I agree with you that the evidence for *piebald* having any role in the etymology of "bald eagle" seems slim.

Answer (score 2):

Even 18th-century authors could not agree on why the bald eagle is so called.

From *T[he Natural History of North-Carolina](https://books.google.it/books?id=p4c5AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA171&dq=%22bald%20eagle%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22bald%20eagle%22&f=false)*, printed in **1737**

[image: snippet from "The Natural History of North-Carolina"]

> The Bald Eagle is the largest, and is so called, because his Head to the middle of the Neck is covered with a white sort of downy Feathers, **whereby it looks very bald**, and the Tail is as white as Snow, the rest of the Body being of a dark brown colour.

But in **1774** the British authors of *[The Beauties of Nature and Art Displayed in a Tour Through the World](https://books.google.it/books?id=Zo4NAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA194&dq=%22bald%20eagle%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22bald%20eagle%22&f=false)*, claimed

> In Virginia, Mr. Clayton informs us, there are three sorts of eagles; the largest of which they call the grey eagle, being much of the colour of our kite or glead: the second is **the bald eagle, so called because the body and part of the neck and head are only covered with a whitish sort of down**; and the third is the black eagle, much resembling those of our own island

Comment: This may be an example of how language speakers (re)interpret a term. Anyway, in my case,  as an English speaker I interpret the term *bald* in *bald eagle* by common sense: the eagle *looks* "bald" (lacking hair on the head) in comparison to other eagles. Whether this is not the actual origin of the term and/or doesn't make scientific sense (the bald eagle does have hair feathers), it's enough to satisfy myself or enough justification for me to tell youngsters when they ask about the term. So, the 'actual' origin doesn't matter for each speaker confronted with the term.

Comment: Each speaker, or generation of speakers,  processes the term for him/her/itself. (So, I wonder if, in the end,  this is similar to the etymological fallacy.)